# One inequality with two variables

Tags: variable, inequalities, system-variables

I would just like to know if this:

```
((a - b)/(b*Log[b])) - Log[Log[a]] + Log[Log[b]]
```

exceeds 0 for any combination of `a` and `b`, being both variables positive integers.

I have tried to compute it on Mathematica but I only get hundreds of errors.

What would be the way to know if there is a solution to

```
((a - b)/(b*Log[b])) - Log[Log[a]] + Log[Log[b]]<0
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Hmmm ... difficult, you could try `FindInstance[((a - b)/(b*Log[b])) - Log[Log[a]] + Log[Log[b]] < 0 && 
  a > 0 && b > b, {a, b}, Integers]` but Mathematica does not give me any instance. Did you take a look at 3D plots of the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mathematical proof would be best, but *Mathematica* can provide some evidence against the statement that

```
f[a_, b_] := ((a - b)/(b*Log[b])) - Log[Log[a]] + Log[Log[b]]
```

is negative for any integer `a, b`.

A straightforward way would be to do

```
NMinimize[{f[a, b], a > 1, b > 1}, {a, b}, Integers]
```

> {0., {a -> 4, b -> 4}}

Indeed, `f[a, b]==0` for `a == b`. Dropping the condition `Integers`,

```
NMinimize[{f[a, b], a > 1, b > 1}, {a, b}]
```

> {-1.11022*10^-16, {a -> 3.71536, b -> 3.71536}}

gives a numerical zero.

A `ContourPlot`:

```
ContourPlot[f[a, b], {a, 1, 10}, {b, 1, 10}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

hints that indeed there are no truly negative values of `f[a, b]` for `a, b >= 1`.

A contour highlighting `f[a, b]==0`:

```
ContourPlot[f[a, b], {a, 1, 10}, {b, 1, 10}, Contours -> {0}]
```

[image]

confirms that `0` is the smallest value attained by `f[a, b]` for positive integer `a, b`.

Answer (score 1):

```
eq = ((a - b)/(b*Log[b])) - Log[Log[a]] + Log[Log[b]];
```

First try with `FindInstance`

```
FindInstance[eq < 0, {a, b}, Integers]
```

FindInstance::nsmet: The methods available to FindInstance are insufficient to find the requested instances or prove they do not exist.

Second try:

```
data = Flatten[Table[{a, b, eq}, {a, 2, 100}, {b, 2, 100}], 1] // N;
MinimalBy[data, Last]
```

[image]

probably never less than zero.

Answer (score 1):

For this case you can try a graphical method. For example:

```
RegionPlot[((a - b)/(b*Log[b])) - Log[Log[a]] + Log[Log[b]] > 0, {a, 
 0, 10}, {b, 0, 10}]
```

It shows the region on the `ab` plane where the inequality is satisfied. Of course you can change the limits for `a` and `b` according to your needs. I've got `a>1` and `b>1` as a solution.